# Select a "column" from a firebase Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, firebase

im working in a project with AngularJS and Firebase, everything working fine.

[image: firebase Data]

But i need to "extract" only temperature values in an array, and then humidity values in other array with javascript of course.

I've been trying with documentation, but i cannot find the way, there isn't a "Select From" method on firebase, could you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the `.map()` functionality in Javascript?

Comment: yes, @GamerNebulae but i'm not sure how it works, so i couldn't figured out :(

Answer (score 2):

How the `map()` function works in Javascript is as follows.

Pretend you have the current data set:

```
var dataSet = [{
    humidity: 10.4,
    temperature: 20.9,
},
{
    humidity: 12.7,
    temperature: 24.2,
}];
```

First off, the function is going to loop over every entry within your data set. This creates a time complexity of `O(n)`. If you're not into speed or it is just a project for fun, don't worry, but it's just something to consider. What the function then does is it returns a new collection based on the actions you did on your data set. In your case, you only want to `return` the humidity field. So, you do this:

```
var dataSet = ...; //See above
var humidityCollection = dataSet.map(function(element) {
  return element['humidity']; //You can also write element.humidity
});
```

Just as a heads up, if you use ECMAScript 6 and above, you can use the function above as a lambda expression. It does the same, but it just shortens the code and it makes it more readable.

```
var humidityCollection = dataSet.map((element) => {
  return element['humidity'];
});
```

This will result in the following data set:

```
[10.4, 12.7]
```

Sources I used and more documentation can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Well, first of all, thank for your help, i tried a function like this, but the output is an empty array

Comment: var incuData = new Firebase('https://birdmaker.firebaseio.com/data');
var completeData = $firebaseArray(incuData);
var humidityCollection = completeData.map(function(element) {
        return element['temp']; //You can also write element.humidity
    });

Comment: @SebasPinto Where does `$firebaseArray` come from?